# sql how do i convert a time series data to a hoc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a sql table which is of this format -

```
Company Size segment        DATE    
ABC     Large cap           01-Mar-98    
ABC     Large cap           01-Sep-98    
ABC     Mid cap             01-Mar-99    
ABC     Mid cap             01-Sep-99    
ABC     Large cap           01-Mar-00
```

i want to convert to this format - The end date is the last date of the each period. For example, the start date for 1st 'Large Cap' period is `01-Mar-98` and the end date for that period is `28-feb-99`.

```
Security    Size segment   Start date   End date       
ABC        Large Cap       01-Mar-98    28-feb-99    
ABC        Mid Cap         1-mar-99     28-feb-00    
ABC        Large Cap       1-mar-00     NULL
```

How do i do it in sql server?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the `28-feb-99` came from as End Date in your result set first row?

Comment: one day prior to third row date (1-mar-99)..that is the company was reviewed semi-annually twice (in Mar 98 and Sep 98) and deemed large cap company...during the third review it was deemed mid cap company. i want this to reflect as being a large cap company for a one-year period Mar 98 to feb 99.

Comment: Why don't you update the question with that, otherwise your sample output doesn't mean anything !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS:

```
CREATE TABLE B
(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Company] varchar(3), [Size segment] varchar(9), [DATE] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO B
([Company], [Size segment], [DATE])
VALUES
('ABC', 'Large cap', '1998-03-01 00:00:00'),
('ABC', 'Large cap', '1998-09-01 00:00:00'),
('ABC', 'Mid cap', '1999-03-01 00:00:00'),
('ABC', 'Mid cap', '1999-09-01 00:00:00'),
('ABC', 'Large cap', '2000-03-01 00:00:00')
;

;WITH tmp AS (
SELECT id, company, [Size segment], [date], row_number() over(order by DATE) row_index
FROM B
)
select b.*, DATEADD(dd, -1, t2.[date])
from B 
left join tmp t1 ON t1.id = b.id
left join tmp t2 ON t1.row_index + 1 = t2.row_index
WHERE t1.[size segment] <> t2.[size segment]
UNION
select TOP 1 *, NULL
from B
ORDER BY [date] DESC
```

Comment: sorry, said it works too quickly..the first row shows up as '1-sep-98' instead of '1-mar-98'. And this solution may not work if i have a time series of many securities. I'm experimenting, but any comments welcome.

Comment: its fine. The first row start date wouldnt be right, but that can be handled separately through an update command. Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Company, [Size segment], Min(DATE) [Start date], MAX(DATE) [End date]
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY Company, [Size segment]
```

Comment: thats what i thought at first, but this solution gives me two rows instead of three, and the start dates and end dates overlap